# Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Platforms' does not exist in the namespace 'MvvmCross' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

Hi I'm newbie in MvvmCross framework and Xamarin.Android development,

I try to follow the TipCalc Android Project tutorial https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/tutorials/tipcalc/a-xamarinandroid-ui-project via this link

However, after I created the Core project, and added the "MainApplication.cs" to the Android Project in the solution (Installed both MvvmCross version 7.2). I cannot reference Platforms package inside MvvmCross.

It gives me the error,

> Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Platforms' does not exist in the namespace 'MvvmCross' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

This should be a simple app tutorial but it has been making me stuck for 2 days. Does anyone have an idea?

MainApplication.cs

```cs
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Runtime;
// These next 2 aren't found
using MvvmCross.Platforms.Android.Core;
using MvvmCross.Platforms.Android.Views;
using TipCalc.Core;

namespace TipCalc.Droid
{
    [Application]
    // So this MvxAndroid... is also not found
    public class MainApplication : MvxAndroidApplication<MvxAndroidSetup<App>, App>
    {
        public MainApplication(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer)
            : base(javaReference, transfer)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I added `MvvmCross` as an assembly reference, but these namespaces aren't showing up. What's going wrong here?

Comment: Please don't post your code as images, instead post it as [properly formatted markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Hi is this OK now, I just show the image to see the context of the issue (error report)

Comment: this is better but could you only show the error as text aswell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are updating an old solution, make sure you change your Android Application project to target Android 10. Otherwise the NuGet package won't install properly for the Android Application. If you are still using packages.config, you may have to uninstall the packages and install them again after changing target.

You can reference the TipCalc sample here: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples/tree/master/TipCalc

Answer (score 1):

Recently the mvvmcross namespaces were changed

it shows that MvvmCross.Platform was changed to MvvmCross

[the changelog](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/upgrading/upgrade-to-mvvmcross-60)

Comment: Thanks, this explains why, but I still need to find out the correct pathway for the package!

Comment: i think you would just remove the .Platform because the documentation doesn't say that the module was removed it just says it was moved

Comment: Although it solved the pathway for Views and Core packages inside MvvmCross. I could not find the change log for the error for MvxAndroidApplication<MvxAndroidSetup<App>, App>


`Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'MvxAndroidApplication<,>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?`

Comment: Make sure you are targeting Android 10

Comment: In the end updating the namespaces according to documentation changes resolved the issue

Comment: As @Cheesebaron said, just make sure you are targeting Android 10.
The latest 7.x version of MvvmCross requires Android 10 or later.
These changes were made in  MvvmCross v 7.0.0.
Check under the section "Removal of monodroid9.0 TFM" in their release notes here: https://www.mvvmcross.com/mvvmcross-7.0.0-release/

Answer (score 0):

Although the reece was correct when there was a codebase change for version 6.0.0 of MvvmCross, the actual solution to my problem, in order to get the tutorial to work is **downgrading MvvmCross package in Nuget to 6.2.1**. I haven't tested with any other versions but 6.2.1 worked for me.

Comment: No need to do that. Updated TipCalc sample can be found here: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples/tree/master/TipCalc